# Angularjs Controller Injection error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

i am updating my question, i am having problem running a code in angularjs, error is coming of controller injection. its a service to retrieve value from the database. i have a json which is providing me json values, but i am finding a little difficult to use mapped values from json in my controller please someone help me in this issue. thanks

**Code**

```
           (function(){
   'use strict';
    angular.module('app').controller('preAuthMinDraftController',preAuthMinDraftController);

    preAuthMinDraftController.$inject=['$http','$scope','preAuthMinDraftService'];
function preAuthMinDraftController($http, $scope,  preAuthMinDraftService)
    {


$scope.getMinValue = function(minValue){

   alert("getMIN Controller");
   $scope.StatusType = "DRAFT";
   $scope.ResultType ="MIN";

       preAuthMinDraftService.getMin($scope.StatusType,$scope.ResultType).then(function(response) {
        if(response.result==true){

              $scope.minValue = response.collections;
              console.log($scope.minValue);


            }else{            
           console.log("Error");
        }  

        },
        function(error){
        console.log("Error");
    }); 



        $scope.minValue.collection = {};
        $scope.minValue.collections.preAuthDashboardVO = {};
        $scope.minValue.collections.preAuthDashboardVO.patientName = patientName;
        $scope.minValue.collections.preAuthDashboardVO.policyNumber = policyNumber;
        $scope.minValue.collections.preAuthDashboardVO.payer = payer;
        $scope.minValue.collections.preAuthDashboardVO.tpaMemberId = tpaMemberId;
        $scope.minValue.collections.preAuthDashboardVO.createdDate = createdDate;
        $scope.minValue.collections.preAuthDashboardVO.preAuthClaimId = preAuthClaimId;
        $scope.minValue.collections.preAuthDashboardVO.preauthClaimIdentifier = preauthClaimIdentifier;



 }



}})();
```

**Services**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('preAuthMinDraftService', preAuthMinDraftService);      
    preAuthMinDraftService.$inject = ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout','$q'];
    function preAuthMinDraftService($http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout,$q) {


this.getMin=function(StatusType,ResultType)
    {
      alert("service");
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var request = $http({
      method : 'POST',

      url : getMinURL,
      headers :{authToken:$rootScope.authToken},
      data :{"StatusType":StatusType,"ResultType":ResultType}

     });

        request.success(function(data) {

         deferred.resolve(data);

        }).error(function(error) {

         deferred.reject(error);

     });

     return deferred.promise;

    };
```

**These are json i have mapped**

```
  $scope.minValue.collection = {};
        $scope.minValue.collections.preAuthDashboardVO = {};
        $scope.minValue.collections.preAuthDashboardVO.patientName = patientName;
        $scope.minValue.collections.preAuthDashboardVO.policyNumber = policyNumber;
        $scope.minValue.collections.preAuthDashboardVO.payer = payer;
        $scope.minValue.collections.preAuthDashboardVO.tpaMemberId = tpaMemberId;
        $scope.minValue.collections.preAuthDashboardVO.createdDate = createdDate;
        $scope.minValue.collections.preAuthDashboardVO.preAuthClaimId = preAuthClaimId;
        $scope.minValue.collections.preAuthDashboardVO.preauthClaimIdentifier = preauthClaimIdentifier;
```

Console Error

```
  preAuthMinDraftController.js:80 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/claimbook/assets/js/momnet.min.js attr @ jquery.min.js:4n.access @ jquery.min.js:2attr @ jquery.min.js:3$set @ angular.js:5830(anonymous function) @ angular.js:15978(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5873$eval @ angular.js:12608$digest @ angular.js:12420$apply @ angular.js:12712(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1419invoke @ angular.js:3918doBootstrap @ angular.js:1417bootstrap @ angular.js:1431angularInit @ angular.js:1344(anonymous function) @ angular.js:21817j @ jquery.min.js:2fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2ready @ jquery.min.js:2I @ jquery.min.js:2
jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/claimbook/assets/js/bootstra.datetimepicker.min.js attr @ jquery.min.js:4n.access @ jquery.min.js:2attr @ jquery.min.js:3$set @ angular.js:5830(anonymous function) @ angular.js:15978(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5873$eval @ angular.js:12608$digest @ angular.js:12420$apply @ angular.js:12712(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1419invoke @ angular.js:3918doBootstrap @ angular.js:1417bootstrap @ angular.js:1431angularInit @ angular.js:1344(anonymous function) @ angular.js:21817j @ jquery.min.js:2fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2ready @ jquery.min.js:2I @ jquery.min.js:2
angular.js:9997 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'preAuthMinDraftController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/ng/areq?p0=preAuthMinDraftController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at http://localhost/claimbook/js/angular.js:78:12
    at assertArg (http://localhost/claimbook/js/angular.js:1481:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://localhost/claimbook/js/angular.js:1491:3)
    at http://localhost/claimbook/js/angular.js:7213:9
    at link (http://localhost/claimbook/js/angular-route.js:913:26)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost/claimbook/js/angular.js:6648:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/claimbook/js/angular.js:6039:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost/claimbook/js/angular.js:5934:30)
    at boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost/claimbook/js/angular.js:6059:21)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost/claimbook/js/angular.js:6669:18)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9997(anonymous function) @ angular.js:7299nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:6651compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6039publicLinkFn @ angular.js:5934boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:6059controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:6669update @ angular-route.js:871$broadcast @ angular.js:12887(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:552wrappedCallback @ angular.js:11498wrappedCallback @ angular.js:11498(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11584$eval @ angular.js:12608$digest @ angular.js:12420$apply @ angular.js:12712done @ angular.js:8315completeRequest @ angular.js:8527xhr.onreadystatechange @ angular.js:8466
custom.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function(anonymous function) @ custom.js:20
```

Comment: Please properly indent the code then you will get an extra '}' is added at the second last line in controller file.

Comment: how do you register `preAuthController`? where is your `preAuthService`?

Comment: I think, he haven't provided the full code of controller js file.

Comment: Maximus services is already there please check in the code

Comment: did solution provided by 2ps helped?

Comment: Maximum yes to some extent solution provided by 2ps has helped me but i need more help with the code to run

Comment: so update your console error, this should not be there `preAuthMinDraftController.js:79 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`. And I still don't see `.controller('preAuthController')` and `.service('preAuthService')` in the code your posted

Comment: Maximum i have updated the code and error again

Comment: remove syntax errors first

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error and just need to take out the parentheses at the end function declaration.  I removed the comments for readability.

```
function preAuthMinDraftController($scope,$rootScope,$location, AuthenticationService,preAuthMinDraftService) {

    $scope.getMinValue=function() {
        console.log("test");
        $scope.StatusType = "DRAFT";
        $scope.ResultType ="MIN";
        preAuthMinDraftService.getMin($scope.StatusType,$scope.ResultType, function (response) {
            console.log(response);                    
        });   
    };    
}
```